# Invalid request payload error when creating attachment in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm using document db and some docs can get so large that they exceed the size limit (2MB). I am trying to store the large chunks as attachments, and here's my code snippet:

```
var stringifiedItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc.Items);
var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringifiedItems));
doc.Attachment = await _client.CreateAttachmentAsync(GetDocumentLink(docId), attachmentStream, new MediaOptions()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Slug = "Items.json"
    });
```

But the CreateAttachmentAsync() call always throws a generic error:

> "The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid request payload."

Can someone shed light on what I'm missing with my code, or give suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we set the `ContentType` through `MediaOptions`, it will set the `Content-Type` HTTP request headers. However the method `CreateAttachmentAsync` with `MemoryStream` parameters will send the request with no body data so this is route cause for the issue payload is invalid.

To fix this issue, instead of set the `ContentType` to `application/json`, we can use the `application/octet-stream` to upload the stream objects.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That addressed my issue.

Comment: @Jiaye If the post is helpful to resolve issue, you can accept it as answer so that other communities who have the same issue could recognize the answer easily.